# My program can not be executed directly but can be invoked as child process

Tags: linux

I have a program running on linux named TestIntf. at beginning it worked perfectly.
But oneday I found out it could not run directly from command line anymore.

Whenever I tried to run: `./TestIntf` it failed.

But when I tried to invoke it as child process by putting it on python code as below:

```
import os
os.system('./TestIntf')
```

TestIntf has worked when I executed the above code.
I am so confused why now its just run as a child process only.
Anyone experienced same thing ? Please help me clarify it

Any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: please clarify "it failed"

Comment: It failed meaned when I checked whether its running by command: 'ps -ef | grep TestIntf | egrep -v grep' but there was nothing in ouput. So I guess it was crashed in somehow.